# MySql query on comparing order contents

Tags: mysql

Long story short I'm working on something in Mysql that has the following tables (with the important parts only)

```
Order (ID, ...)
OrderItems (OrderID, ItemID, ...)
Item (ID, ...)
```

Now I want to write a query to find the all orders that have the exact same items bought.

Example:

Order Table

```
O1
O2
O3
O4
O5
```

Items Table

```
I1
I2
I3
I4
```

OrderItems Table

```
O1     I1
O1     I2
O1     I3
O1     I4
O2     I1
O2     I3
O2     I4
O3     I1
O3     I4
O4     I1
O4     I3
O4     I4
O5     I1
O5     I4
```

Expected output:

```
O2   
O4
O3
O5
```

This would be because O2 and O4 have the same items (1, 3, 4) and 
O3 and O5 have the same items (1, 4)
(Order of this output doesn't really matter to me).

How would I go about doing this? I have this vague idea that I'd have to make a query that gets all the Items in my first order, and then compare it to the list of all the items for every other order, but I don't really know how to go about making a query with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Long story short http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I thought my worded example was enough, clearly not. Sorry about that, i should have put in more effort into explaining what I wanted.

Comment: @MichaelBrowning Why did you expect result only number instead of `Order` number

Comment: I left that in from the previous example, it should be the order number. Updated.

Comment: @MichaelBrowning I answered your question you can try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query. use `group_concat` function to get the `ItemID` and `COUNT` list by `OrderID` in subquery.

then write another subquery to get `group_concat` List and `join` and get `COUNT` greater than one, which means have the same `ItemID` by `OrderID`

```
SELECT OrderID
FROM (
  SELECT grp,count(*) cnt
  FROM (
    select OrderID,group_concat(ItemID ORDER BY ItemID) grp
    from OrderItems 
    group by OrderID 
  ) t 
  group by grp
) t1
INNER JOIN (
  select OrderID,group_concat(ItemID ORDER BY ItemID) grp
  from OrderItems 
  group by OrderID 
) t2 on t1.grp = t2.grp and t1.cnt > 1
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48f6c6/5)

**[Results]**:

```
| OrderID |
|---------|
|      O2 |
|      O3 |
|      O4 |
|      O5 |
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you so much for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **group_concat** :

```
select OrderId,group_concat(ItemID order by ItemID ) as ListItems 
         from OrderItems
         group by OrderId 
         order by ListItems ;
```

More documentation on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Be aware that the variable  **group_concat_max_len** will change the result .